# Get old git 1.7 to basically create the same as the 'git tag --merged' command, for database schema updates

Tags: git, database-schema, git-tag

I am looking to coordinate MySQL database schema updates with commits to git.

My initial plan was to tag commits with a schema number, e.g., git tag schema19936 b6671a2c1. Then I could 'git tag --merged' to see if the tag is available on the current branch, if so then run the schema19936 script.

Unfortunately, we are still supporting CentOS 6 which includes git 1.7. Git 1.7 does not include the '--merged' flag in git tag, so my does will no longer work.

Background: We are coming from subversion and previously had used the revision number as our criteria to see the code requires a schema update.

Are there any work arounds in old git 1.7 to basically create the same as the 'git tag --merged' command. Or is there a better way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `--merged` does is test ancestry, so you can do that manually.  That is, tag *T* "is merged into" commit *C* if *T <sup>commit</sup>* ≤ *C*.  The "≤" test for commits is implemented with `git merge-base --is-ancestor`, and turning *T* into its commit *T <sup>commit</sup>* is easily done with [`gitrevisions` syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) by appending `^{commit}`.  (If tag *T* points to something other than a commit, this will fail noisily, with a message to stderr.)

Unfortunately, `git merge-base --is-ancestor` was added in Git 1.8.

Fortunately, [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html) has a literal bit of shell script showing the "old way" of doing what is more nicely expressed via this `--is-ancestor` test:

> A common idiom to check "fast-forward-ness" between two commits A and B is (or at least used to be) to compute the merge base between A and B, and check if it is the same as A, in which case, A is an ancestor of B. You will see this idiom used often in older scripts.
>
> ```
> A=$(git rev-parse --verify A)
> if test "$A" = "$(git merge-base A B)"
> then
>     ... A is an ancestor of B ...
> fi
> ```
>
> In modern git, you can say this in a more direct way:
>
> ```
> if git merge-base --is-ancestor A B
> then
>     ... A is an ancestor of B ...
> fi
> ```
>
> instead.

Simply substitute in the old test, using `T^{commit}` for the initial `A` and `$C` (our commit to test) for `B`:

```
A=$(git rev-parse T^{commit}) || exit 1
if test $A = "$(git merge-base A $C)"; then ...; fi
```

Comment: this worked, I was able to implement 'git tag --merged' albeit much slower.